Pilots crash-landing in Australia, natives passing message over long distance
I dimly remember a movie I've seen on German Free TV in the 80's or possibly 90's, but which might have been older than that (but in color, not B/W).
It's about two pilots surviving a crash landing of their plane (mail?) in Australia. From the type of airplane, I would say 1920's, 1930's. Injured, and short / out of potable water, the pilots make contact with a couple of natives, who promise to pass word of their plight to somewhere (a mission? outpost? don't know anymore).
The movie is mostly about the pilot's struggle (drinking water from the engine's cooler, I think I remember that part), but there is mention about how the natives crossed a huge distance, on foot, in exceptionally little time, shortening the time till search parties locate the pilots.
Does anyone remember the title of that movie?

Parts of this sound like The Riddle of the Stinson, I cant be sure as the hero of this  story is Bernard O’Reilly. Unless when you say native you don't mean Aboriginal but simply someone living in Australia.

@YetisasquatchAlienbeliever: Yes, the IMDB summary does ring a few bells, but after looking at a few scenes of it on YouTube, I don't think this is what I saw back then. But looks like a good movie of its own, thanks for pointing it out.
